# Is there any way to let Postgres know it can filter results and then calculate aggregations?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance, aggregate, running-totals

Given a table A with 10 million records and another table B with child items (one-to-many), I have to provide a consumable view with totals from several fields in B grouped by the FK of A.

None of the filtering or sorting I'm doing are reliant upon the aggregated totals, but the performance is poor even when I'm doing a simple filter on a column that is in table A such as a smallint (status_id, etc.). The analyzer appears to try to perform aggregations on the total result set before applying my filter.

Because I have to use max(id), etc. on all of my columns in table A even though I know they are distinct, I'm wondering if that's causing an issue because I'm technically filtering on an aggregate value? If that's the case, I would expect subqueries to perform better.

Comment: This is much too vague to be answerable.  Please show a specific query which shows the problem (reduced to the simplest which still does show the problem) and a specific query plan `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for it.  It might not cover every situation, but at least we will know what it is you are describing.

Comment: I'll work on that. The point is fair.

Answer (score 1):

Be explicit about what you want and put your filter into a subquery in `FROM`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT ...
      FROM a
      WHERE /* your filter */) AS a_filtered
   JOIN b ON ...
GROUP BY ...
```

Comment: I'm using this view in order to support paging (in general no one will ever need to go past the first page so there will only be a limit of 10 applied, and I'm fine with page 2 taking a while) and to allow for dynamic filtering and sorting on the non-aggregate values. I use an ORM against the view to support this. Is this only possible if I use raw sql or a function to build out a filter each time?

Comment: Depends on the filter - if the variation is just in constants, it is easy. Otherwise, you may need dynamic SQL. ORMs make many tasks easier, but if the tool doesn't do the trick, don't be shy to use SQL or a function.